# Quorum Configuration

Tags: windows, clustering, failover

I have watched many sample videos in youtube.com and discovered that in this videos in windows failover cluster dashboard configuration looks like this :

Quorum Configuration: Node and Disk Majority (Cluster Disk 1)

But on my dashboard it looks like:

Witness: Disk (Cluster Disk 1)

What is the cause of this difference. I am using Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard Edition

Comment: For which DBMS do you want to do that?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about database administration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They changed the layout of the cluster manager screens (and some of the terminology) from Windows Server 2008 R2 -> 2012. It's not a meaningful difference; watch newer videos.